# Is it possible, in any language, to implement rules that will affect every instance of an object?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design, rule

For example, could I implement a rule that would change every string that followed the pattern '1..4' into the array [1,2,3,4]? In JavaScript:

```
//here you create a rule that changes every string that matches /$([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)*/
//ever created into range($1,$2) (imagine a b are the results of the regexp)
var a = '1..4';
console.log(a);
>> output: [1,2,3,4];
```

Of course, I'm pretty confident that would be impossible in most languages. My question is: is there any language in which that would be possible? Or have anyone ever proposed something like that? Does this thing have a 'name' for which I can google to read more about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying the language from whithin itself falls under the umbrell of reflection and [metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming). It is referred as *behavioral* reflection. It differs from *structural* reflection that opperates at the level of the application (e.g. classes, methods) and not the language level. Support for behavioral reflection varies greatly across languages.

We can broadly categorize language changes in two categories:

1. changes that modify the semantics (i.e. the rules) of the language itself (e.g. redefine the method lookup algorithm),
2. changes that modify the syntax (e.g. your syntax '1..4' to create arrays).

For case 1, certain languages expose the structure of the application (structural reflection) and the inner working of their implementation (behavioral reflection) to the application itself via special object, called meta-objects. Meta-objects are [reifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_%28computer_science%29) of otherwise implicit aspects, that become then explicitely manipulable: the application can modify the meta-objects to redefine part of its structure, or part of the language. When it comes to langauge changes, the focus is usually on modifiying message sending / method invocation since it is the core mechanism of object-oriented language. But the same idea could be applied to expose other aspects of the language, e.g. field accesses, synchronization primitives, foreach enumeration, etc. depending on the language.

For case 2, the program must be representated in a suitable data structure to be modified. For languages of the lisp family, the program manipulates lists, and the program can be itself represented as lists. This is called [homoiconicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) and is handy for metaprogramming, hence the flexibility of lisp-like languages. For other languages, their representation is usually an AST. Transforming the representation of the program, or rewriting it, is possible with macro, preprocessors, or hooks during compilation or class loading.

The line between 1 and 2 is however blurry. Syntactical changes can appear to modify the semantics of the language. For instance, I can rewrite all fields accesses with proper getter and setter and perform additional logic there, say to implement transactional memory. Did I perform a semantical change of what a field access is, or merely a syntax change? 
Also, there are other constructs the fall bewten the lines. For instance, proxies and `#doesNotUnderstand` trap are popular techniques to simulate the reification of message sends to some extent.

Lisp and Smalltalk have been very influencial in the field of metaprogramming, and I think the two following projects/platform are interesting to look at for a representative of each of these:

- [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/), a lisp-like language focused on growing languages from within the langauge
- [Helvetia](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/helvetia), a Smalltalk extension to embed new languages into the host language by leveraging the AST of the host environment.

I hope you enjoyed this even if I did not really address your question ;)

Your desired change require modifying the way literals are created. This is AFAIK not usually exposed to the application. The closed work that I can think of is [Virtual Values for Language Extension](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2048066.2048136), that tackled Javascript.

Comment: -1 Reification is not merely about the inner workings - anything that is a first class object is reified.

Comment: Thanks for the Helvetia link; I had completely forgotten about that. Curse you for the Helvetia link, now I have another half-dozen papers to read :p

Comment: @Marcin I don't see how one contradicts the other.

Comment: @ewernli And that is why your answer is misleading.

Comment: @Marcin And that is why I would appreciate if you expand and can give an example of a first-class object that does not connect to an element of the inner workings, and explain why it fails to do so in your view.

Comment: @ewernli The distinction you are contending for does not exist. Anything that exists as a first class object is reified. You could choose to view anything as part of the inner workings, even a user defined class. Your statement is misleading because it implies that (a) there is some class of objects available in the language that are not reified; and (b) that the term has a proper application to something which does not exist.

Comment: @Marcin I did not imply this distinction. (a) I'm fine with: all first-class objects reify elements of the inner workings, but not all elements of the inner workings are reified. My statement was supposed to emphasis the second part (b) Fair enough, you don't like the term "inner workings". Do you have a better term to intuitively capture "what" a first-class object reifies?

Comment: @ewernli A first class object reifies whatever it reifies. There is no particular limit on what can be reified, except perhaps the very outer bounds of theoretical computability - anything that can be represented can be reified.

Comment: @Marcin Oh well, since there is no established term, I will define one: it's called "inner workings" ;) Thanks.

Comment: @ewernli Which is misleading.

Comment: @Marcin There's structural reflection (e.g. classes and methods as objects) and behavioral reflection (e.g. #doesNotUnderstand, stack reification). One is about reflecting on the application, the other about reflecting on the execution of the application (conceptually, the interpreter running the application). In retrospect, I think what you meant is that my wording put too much emphasis on behavioral reflection, and not structural reflection. Is that correct?

Comment: No what I mean is that it sounds like reification is a way of exposing interpreter internals.

Comment: @Marcin Despite starting with no, you basically answered yes: exposing interpreter internals is behavioral reflection. You find that my answer is not covering structural reflection. We can reify aspects of the interpreter, but *also of the application (e.g. classes and methods)*. You find that the part in italic was missing. Correct?

Comment: @ewernli It's not just that the reference is missing. Reification isn't naturally about one or the other, and internals can be exposed with reification.

Comment: @Marcin Actually, it's about one or the other. There are lots of research papers using this terminology, e.g. www.emn.fr/x-info/emoose/alumni/thesis/pebraert.pdf. My answer is indeed mostly about behavioral reflection, hence the possibly misleading. According to your comments, we can't establish different kinds of reflection/reification. But at the very same time your use of "merely" in the very first comment suggests the existence of different forms of reflection/reification. Too bad I couldn't nail down the confusion between us--I honestly tried since I like the topic.

Comment: @ewernli I think the problem is that you are not a native user of English; either that or you don't pay close attention to what you are reading. *"Actually, it's about one or the other."* is not an answer to my point that reification isn't naturally about one or the other forms of reflection. The point I am making is that of those two things (leaving aside whether or not there may be more things it is about) it is not naturally affiliated, as a term, more with one of those than  with the the other one. To suggest otherwise is to mislead.

Comment: @Marcin I indeed find obscure the way you express yourself. Not sure the problem is entirely on my side, though. Anyway, I've updated the anwser to something I believe is better and gives justice to both forms of reflection, taking into consideration what I could grasp from your comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Common Lisp (and certain other lisps) have "reader macros" which allow the user to reprogram (incrementally) the mapping between the input stream and the actual language construct as parsed.

See http://dorophone.blogspot.com/2008/03/common-lisp-reader-macros-simple.html

If you want to operate on the level of objects, you will want to use a debugging/memory management framework that keeps track of all objects, and processes the rules on each evaluation step (nasty). This seems like the kind of thing you might be able to shoehorn into smalltalk.

Comment: This is interesting but Im not sure this can do what I want. For example, I would want to set a rule that would change ALL objects in my program that have x>10 into x=10. That is, if anytime on runtime I updated a hash setting it's x to 20, it would automatically correct it into 10. Is this possible?

Comment: Processing them on every step, you mean, like a loop? That would not be very elegant but is indeed a solution. If I could, though, change the behaviour of the 'setter' of an object, I could do so that every object changed gets automatically checked for rule matches. Hmm... now if a language allowed that

Comment: @Dokkat Evaluation is a loop. You would be altering the evaluation step of a read-eval-(print)-loop.

Answer (score 3):

[CLOS (Common Lisp Object System)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp_Object_System) allows redefinition of live objects.

Ultimately you need two things to implement this:

1. Access to the running system's [AST (Abstract Syntax Tree)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), and
2. Access to the running system's objects.

You'll want to study [meta-object protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaobject#Metaobject_protocol) and the languages that use them, then the implementations of both the MOPs and the environment within which these programs are executed.

Image-based systems will be the easiest to modify (e.g., Lisp, potentially Smalltalk).

([Image-based systems](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ImageBasedLanguage) store a snapshot of a running system, allowing complete shutdown and restarts, redefinitions, etc. of a complete environment, including existing objects, and their definitions.)

Comment: Pardon, what? CLOS? AST? MOP? Image-based systems? I'm on my way of googling those but the answer would be more complete if you explained what they mean on the context of the question.

Comment: @Dokkat I hear you, but won't; that would be paragraphs of exposition. I'll add definitions, that's all.

Comment: Thanks, knowing what is AST helped (I had no idea of what you were talking about before). Might I just ask, what do you mean with CLOS allows redefinition of live objects?

Comment: @Dokkat Pretty much precisely that. In a running system, if you redefine a class, you must also redefine *instances* of that class. [This discusses it briefly](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/clos-tutorial/index.html#section-3.7), anything further you'll have to dive into CLOS proper.

Comment: @Dokkat AST is a standard term. I honestly think you're out of your depth if you don't know it. Evaluate whether an alternate strategy might be better, after you have completed your research.

Comment: @Dokkat I have to agree with Marcin. What's your ultimate goal? Program transformation? System updating? Knowing your goal(s) in context may help us.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby allows you to extend classes.  For instance, this example [adds functionality to the String class](http://snipplr.com/view/23211/).  But you can do more than add methods to classes.  You can also overwrite methods, but defining a method that's already been defined.  You may want to preserve access to the original method using [alias_method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-alias_method).

Putting all this together, you can overload a constructor in Ruby, but in your case, there's a catch:  It sounds like you want the constructor to return a different type.  Constructors by definition return instances of their class.  If you just want it to return the string "[1,2,3,4]", that's simple enough:

```
class string
  alias_method :initialize :old_constructor
  def initialize
    old_constructor
    # code that applies your transformation
  end
end
```

But there's no way to make it return an Array if that's what you want.

Comment: Not in `initialize`, but you can implement your own `new`. This may or may not lead to expected behavior, but you *can*.